# Python socket connection opened but no data is transferred

Tags: python, sockets, networking, connection

I have been using sockets for a while in Python, but I recently observed some unexpected behavior when the script is being run for a long time. Basically the connection seems to still be alive while not being able to pass messages anymore.

I wrote a very basic server client code to illustrate the problem.

Server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(ADDRESS)
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
i = 0
while True:
    print(i, conn.recv(1024))
    conn.sendall(b'Hello back client')
    i += 1
```

Client:

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(ADDRESS)
i = 0
while True:
    s.sendall(b'Hello server')
    print(i, s.recv(1024))
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run both scripts simultaneously (one on my local client and one on my remote server), I can see all messages being printed every second.

However, when he client computer goes to sleep mode after a few minutes, the connection seems to stop in an unnatural way: the server doesn't raise any exception and hangs on `print(i, conn.recv(1024))`, while the client apparently succeeds in sending the message but raises a `TimeoutError` at `print(i, s.recv(1024))`.

The last lines printed on the server are

```
184 b'Hello server'
185 b'Hello server'
```

and on the client

```
184 b'Hello back client'
185 b'Hello back client'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

If I don't kill the server process, I can reconnect to the same adress from the client but no messages are passed anymore. A call to `sendall()` succeeds on both sides but a call to `recv()` just hangs even though the other end of the connection just sent some data.

Does someone know what happens there and how to handle those cases?

Btw my server is a private VPS running on CentOS 8 (python 3.9.5) and my client is running on Windows 11 (python 3.10.9).

Comment: If you leave it alone for perhaps 10 minutes does the server also time out? Some operating systems have very long timeouts

Comment: It specifically happens when the client computer goes into sleep mode but the script is running in the background. I suspect it has to do with how the OS handles open connections in sleep mode.

Comment: the OS does not handle open connections in sleep mode. The connection is broken. I notice that the server and client are using different operating systems. Different operating systems have different timeouts. Sometimes the timeouts are very long. Maybe after 10 minutes or 20 minutes the server will time out.

Comment: But if one end of the connection times out, shouldn't it raise an error on the other end of the connection?

Comment: Apparently it doesn't tell the other end that it timed out. (I suppose that makes sense, because if it timed out, that means it thinks the other end totally disappeared e.g. power cord pulled out)